# Setting GITHUB_TOKEN within Docker Image still causes manual auth

Tags: python, docker, github

I have a docker image which I am trying to run some git commands in an automation script, I am using the Github CLI for this.

Just for testing locally I am manually setting the token from Github using Python like so:

```
import os
os.environ['GITHUB_TOKEN'] = token
```

I would expect this to allow me to run the following commands without asking me to login:

```
git clone project
cd project
```

But when I run the docker image it keeps asking me for my `Username` & `Password` to Github:

```
Cloning into 'project'...
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

Running `gh auth status` outputs:

```
github.com
  ✓ Logged in to github.com as yudhiesh (GITHUB_TOKEN)
  ✓ Git operations for github.com configured to use https protocol.
  ✓ Token: *******************
```

Which should mean I am authenticated but why is it asking me for my username and password again?

Comment: You mean to say `os.environ['GITHUB_TOKEN'] = token` is already in the code , which is docker ?

Comment: @LeiYang tried that now its saying `The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.113.4)' can't be established.`. Seems like the token doesn't have sufficient access which is odd as I specified that the token has `Full control of private repositories` and `admin:org`. Also the repo is a private repo within my org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to update the URL I cloned from to `git clone https://MY_TOKEN@github.com/user-or-org/repo`.